docker-python error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'
i'm running a python/django app using docker and apache2 and it was working great ,, but suddnle when I try to run again am getting this error :
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen site>", line 201, in addpackage
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'

Remainder of file ignored
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen site>", line 201, in addpackage
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distutils-precedence.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen site>", line 201, in addpackage
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_distutils_hack'

Remainder of file ignored
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.395312 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422] mod_wsgi (pid=26): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/wsgi.py'.
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.395343 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422] mod_wsgi (pid=26): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/wsgi.py'.
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.395501 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.401671 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422]   File "/var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.401687 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed May 29 15:43:45.401704 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 26:tid 132520276391616] [client 172.27.0.1:40422] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Here is an example of used files in the project :
Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

# Avoid tzdata infinite waiting bug
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Africa/Cairo

RUN apt clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils git
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt update
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt -y install python3.10-full
# Optional: Set Python 3.9 as the default Python version
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
# RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN apt -y install certbot python3-certbot-apache
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt update
# Check Python and pip versions
RUN python3 --version && \
    pip3 --version
#Add sf to avoid ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/bin/pip': File exists
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --break-system-packages
RUN pip install django ptvsd --break-system-packages
RUN apt install wait-for-it
RUN pip install cffi --upgrade --break-system-packages
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools --break-system-packages
RUN apt-get -y install gettext
RUN apt-get -y install poppler-utils
RUN apt-get -y install redis-server
RUN apt-get install python3-pymysql
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN service apache2 restart
COPY www/demo_app/water_maps/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 5432
WORKDIR /var/www/html/demo_app
#CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
#CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]

docker-compose.yaml
version: "2"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_USER=database_user_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Yahoo000@

  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: water_maps
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_USER=database_user_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Yahoo000@
    ports:
      - 5000:80
      - 5001:443
      # - 80:80
      # - 443:443

    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2

      # - ./data/config/etc/apache2:/etc/apache2
    # command: sh -c 'python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py loaddata the_db.json '
    command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py compilemessages && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    # command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata last.json && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'

    depends_on:
      - db

/demo_site.conf
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/demo_app

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        # ServerName test3.watermaps-eg.com
        # ServerAlias test3.watermaps-eg.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/



       Alias /static /var/www/html/demo_app/static
       Alias /en/upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload
       Alias /ar/upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload
       Alias /upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/upload>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        TimeOut 7200
</VirtualHost>

